# How are trigonometric functions used in this sketch to make one object move towards another?

Tags: trigonometry, p5.js

So I asked a someone to help me with a small project ( ball chases ball you control one)
and he gave me a trigonometric thing, it works very well can someone explain trigonometry to me?

Heres the code he gave me:

```
var aiX = 0;
var aiY = 0;

var playerX = 200;
var playerY = 200;

draw = function () {
  background(255);
  
  playerX = mouseX;
  playerY = mouseY;
  
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  ellipse(playerX, playerY, 50, 50);
  
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(aiX, aiY, 50, 50);
  
  var angle = atan2(playerY - aiY, playerX - aiX);
  aiX += cos(angle);
  aiY += sin(angle);
  
  if (dist(playerX, playerY, aiX, aiY) < 50) {
    text("ouch!", 100, 100);
  }
};
```

How i changed it:

```js
var aiX = 200;
var aiY = 0;

function setup() {
  playerX = 200;
  playerY = 200;
}

draw = function () {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(255);
  let h = hour();
  //scare anyone
  if (h === 3) {
    console.log("I SEE YOU");
    let img = createImg(imageData, "YOU CANT HIDE EVEN IF I WONT LOAD");
  }
  if (isKeyPressed && keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    playerY = playerY - 5;
  }
  if (isKeyPressed && keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    playerY = playerY + 5;
  }
  if (isKeyPressed && keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    playerX = playerX + 5;
  }
  if (isKeyPressed && keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    playerX = playerX - 5;
  }

  fill(0, 255, 0);
  ellipse(playerX, playerY, 50, 50);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(aiX, aiY, 50, 50);
  function reset() {
    playerX = 200;
    playerY = 200;
    aiX = 200;
    aiY = 15;
  }

  var angle = atan2(playerY - aiY, playerX - aiX);
  aiX += cos(angle);
  aiY += sin(angle);

  if (dist(playerX, playerY, aiX, aiY) < 50) {
    console.log("GAMEOVER");
    reset();
  }
};


const imageData = 
  "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHCBISEhIREhIRERISEhISEREREhEPEQ8SGBQZGRgUGBgcIS4lHB4rHxgYJjgmKy8xNTU1GiQ7QDs0Py40NTEBDAwMEA8QGBISGDEdGCExMTQxNDExMTE0NDE0NDExNDQ0MTE0NDQ0NDQxMT8xPz8/NDE0NDExMTQ0NDExMTExMf/AABEIAOEA4QMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAABBQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAYFBwj/xAA8EAACAQMBBgMGBQMBCQEAAAAAAQIDBBEhBQYSMUFRYXGxBxMiMoGRFEJScqEjNGIkM3ODksHC0eHwJf/EABkBAAMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAwIEBf/EAB8RAQEBAQADAAMBAQAAAAAAAAABAhEDITEEEkEyIv/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A2cPlX7V6FafMsx+VftXoVp8xwiRY9DIokwAACoGAIef79b5KCla20lKck1UmvyeCfcTfffT3fHa2/wA+sak8/L4LxPMJTcm2223q29W2Bicm3lvL8Rg5Rb5D40JvlF/YVp8qICeVrUSy4SS8iHADhAAAIAA5Rb5LIA0CSNGT6A6TQuglObjJSi2pJpprmmup6ruXvmq+KFy4xqJYhPRKfh5nk46E3FqSbTTymtGmMPpGLAwO42+Pvmra5kveaRpT5caxyfjob4CoAMBgbJrEQrBCopJEZIxrQihoAAGux5L9q9CvJalmK+FftXoQtDapkUPQqQ5IYIkZjfzbP4S1fA3GpVfBBrnHq5fY1ODw7fza0ri7mtVCl8EI+XNgGcnNyblJttvLb1bfdj7ag5ySX1IUjQbMt1FJ90Y3r9Y3nPU9ts2Cw8aouOljp/A+NWMVqylX2ksnL+2rXTJmRZcejIJ2FOa1il5EVLaMZPUuQqJ8h91D5mubU2UtcLQqy2WaFxyiCtBJcxTyaF8eXDVjGPNEmIpdB9xUOdXqMrm60lqZiac0QTnkgc2JxFJlO2ElzEADbB9Obi1KLaknlNaNM9y3K2v+LtISbzUh8E++V1PCkbL2a7TlSu1R5wrJpr/JcmgD2QGhyQjQ2ETQmCRjQPhuBrRIMYuETAC5AODq3BaL9q9CFktPkvJehGwaLEdgbBDxhT2tX93b1aieHCnJp+OD53uKrqTlOTzKUnJvu2z1n2kbwSpRVpTa4qkG6jay1Dkl9TyScMC6C28OKSRpYNRS8jgWEfiO3dS4KfER8nu8W8aldXDb4VltvCS5vwNBsvcC8rwVSUfdxaylPRs6e4+zLe3tqm1ryKmoZVCEuUpdHg4W3t/726m3Go6NPPwwp/DhG84kK6Rbb3Tu7TM5wcqa/PHVfwUrG4zoSWG913Tb45utCWk6dT4lJdfIjjUo/iIypN+7qPWEtHCT5oNZnBNe3UhVIrirk073bbp8axjGTL7Qp+7bT6HJ2W+nT745dzNcyxsHYFS8qcMcqC1nPokc+s3J8K5t4S7s3W8V4tmWdC0ovhr1YcdaaxxRTXLJ1Yjm3VG+3Vsab4XdqMknlS1y/Aye0tnzoTw9Yv5JrWMl5lSpUlJuUm5N823kuWl62vdVHxU5fq14X0a7Fak54D5xw2ueGxjQjBa2dcypVadSEnGUJxaa6a6/wVR8IZAPpKhPihCX6oxf3Q/BivZzvBO4hO2rPiqUYxlTl1nB6YfijboIXDJojJZkbQwQbIcIwZsNAAAcWo8l5L0IyVcl+1egxoGhEegihcAHivtGqf8A6Nb9tPH/ACmRqdDX+02g4385dKlOnJfRYMhU6eRlpf2TSzI6e2YYpfVEOxoYwzrXdNThKPdENa/6WzPS1vVWcdk7PpxeFLLklybPP2byhS/HWEbbiXv7aT4IPRyh3Ribq2nTk4Ti4yXNMvEaiySUPnj+5epGdPYNk6tWKxonlhq8lPM7Y9ctrtK1Wmvu19dDzrbdT42a6dfhhjOiWDB7XrcU2cGM9313a9ZQWDj+Io8Xy+9pp57cSO17T442jUSzwqFPh7Y4ehl5y6rmuXgd/ee9jd0ba5zmrGCo1l1Tj8rfmd2XFpmWxAA0wVA0Ogh2BWnEQ+LwmNY6CymMm49lk83v/AqZ+6wevpHk3sjtm7urPGlOi032cnov4Z64kEF+GSRE0TSGYGzEWBGiVoYwNHgBwAFlcl5L0EYq5LyXoI0KFToi5EQoyYD2o2kJRo1MfEnJZ7rseWTp5ml0PcN99mSuLWXu4uVSm+KKXN90eT2my5KTdSLi0+T0aZPWuLYnV7Z9viJcdPngmpU8JJFqFq3rg4tb9urOfTN3FrNT46cnCfSUdGc+7tq1SbnUbnJ85PmzbSs89CCVul0KTzFfDGOttiznLsuuTXbNs4UopRWvfuOhDsXrag20nyM78t1OKY8UlQV3mLRi9qUmpN+LN9tW1939smO2qll55C8V9jzX/ln2I1pgkcddBOE7OuLiHgFjAsRgLwh+xfqiwDQ6bI2wnszHElto/ENNDubseN3cKnJtRS4pY0bS6D6XHoHswt4xtqk0tZ1NX3SRtyls2wp29NU6a4YLpz16suZNRjQaGD2MwNmU2SGSRKxriDSIB/CABMunkvQEg6LyXoAi0UQAGyjrz4YSl2Tf2PLa03UqTl+qTf8AJ6Vtapw0Kku0WecUI6nN57x0+CdT0aZfc1oljIyhSytB1KEYPL5nA7lyMfgOZcx1kzpuceH5vp1OfW14uw4OqdKaXMdPbFKElDi+Lp2Ry7qv8XCumpRVrCUszzq+j6lZJfrP7O9tXaTnFZaeOvgYrad1ltLqda6i8cMXy01M3dRfE8lvDmdR8uvQpVCTizgppk8ZHRY55V1wwRTY6hPKwJVgYbV5kUiSYmDcZpEbr2Wr/VTf+DMKkbn2XVIq5km9XDQKT17AgAbnxHX0AAo2TWNaJGNBqUgCAB9PXJeS9ADt5L0FENEABRsuTvNPFrU8Ul/Jgbd6m93n/tZ/T1MHQj6nJ+Q6/A6kJOKxHnIVW0sN5yyShHK16EsZPLba4eSx365OJ2ORWz3xgp3F1wJ6ttnQvacfix1zgz1eLcuD7m88HD7SHE231/gvzseLh4dMMnsrLGNDqOhhBdcEz1mLxKm0ubMxtKGJP7mi2vPNR/wcLaMW39Do8VQ8uXIwPiyRQHqkdN1HNw62niSZduo6FNUi3SlxpprPCv4MWtxRaE4SzwDJxDo4gwdzdC89zd0pdHJJ/XQ4sifZ08VabXSpH1NMV9FLkAyg8wi+8Y+g8pPiOvoABRlAIxcCMD/puADIAZ3byXoAdvJegCGgAANhU2rbe8pTh3Tx5nntOLhJxfNNo9NMnvRs9RarRWn5sepz+fPY6PDripZSy8FucUs8kuyOTaVVnPZl6pW8dWcFjvz7ineuK1M9Qjx1tOrO1fPMJaa50E2JaR4HN/O5PT/Ec9NV2rC3jGPxds5I7mWIvxR0baCcFnRLTLKt3CLWFjkYt9t5+MFtBL3n1KO1aa6F/bNNxqPzK95Diin4HVi/HP5MuCok0EPnDA1Fu9c/6+w4klppJruhsR1Jf1Ih05k6pTwVaqOvcx+E5VXqKUairInsI5q08frj6kEjbezrYDq1FczX9Om/hz+aRVLVesWqxTgnzUY5+xIIhxSfEdfSCoQchjIEY4QDv0zADsABDt5L0EBcl5L0AR6AAA2CkNzbxqQcJLKksMlFFZ05ePOr+1dCrKD5ZzHxQ6Um0sP/ANGh3utk6caiWqkk34MzEJ6NHneXPNPS8OuxHeXHAteqwGx60scWdFoihtmbwl06nR2VPijGGF8KXLqZs9LNTQnmmk1z1ObOL4mdi1gnFLwOZdZjN5If1bPxiNtzzUfngdcwXu0/Ift2j/UeOTeRlanJU1nsjqz8jn39rhXK1K6eGWq5Smy+XLfqxEfDSUX2Y2xXE2u2pLWjjHmvUDyt11lHHrvU6NxWxlI5VaeR5nstVc2Js2V1cU6EfzS+J9odWe7bMsKdvThSprEYJLz8TCeyjZi4Kt00suXu4d0ktT0dIvIhqhCgIaSKOiho9IDgaGsexkgaIAgAXAuS8l6AC5LyXoAhoAADYAAABR23R47eoufw5X0PP4yPTpRTTT1T0aPOL+291VqQ7SzHyZy+fP8AXb+Pr1xxNrza+pb2PWajnyKe2FmK8zo7OofDHskvuc1+OrrV21zL3cXy0IL+5UpKK1aWvmN/FJQSxyObVrJNyysk5n2p+3I5W1Y5mia9go0ksptrXHQ5+1Lz4+mW0F/c/wBPOdcI6JEd664lxHDZSlHLJ7ivkrcZaOerFpU4JZ6PmWJzi5P+DnymJGfqHOlLxYqvVlKoS155fgQy1NZnC1Xt3s+t+DZ9HTDknN+OWaY5m7FPhs7aPanD0OmVz8c+vpMBgXImTTPAiVEJLBgAxshzGsGzQDAADY8l5L0FCPJeS9BRFogAKNggoAAIzJ732+JU6iS+JOL7mtbMnvjcLip009VmTXbsR83+XR4P9MZtGKw89As79pJckLtGGac5dijlRnHOi4EcknXZa7877MdOhz513q2V6t7TjHHFnwRXd3xZfJfc3nDN0p39filnsNr36lTUcYx1yFTDKFysFZlO1DUmQuQkpkbkVmUbUrmPpvJWyTRHYJT5MWHNeaI2x9PmjPBa+g92LqFS1o8ElLFOKfg0jqNHh2zL+4oxVWhN/Bhyhq4v6Ho27G+lC7UYTlwVuTjLRSfgykTrVOAnAyaLFwNlBwMdCBLgUGjHEjZOQyiANAAAKGx7xV6FKqvzwjldpY1RdMP7MdocdvKk3rCWYp/pZt2KFSiNiZGyYyLxC8RE5BkBxDf3saVOU305Luzz2/upVKkpy5yf2Rpt7W+Gm1nGXnsZKstDm82v46fBOIbrWlUXgcCdCrUejytManb95o10awwsqa5d+Rz51x0WdZypaVI80/UglKa042vA27tjn3VlTz8iK53C1hmIqb5Sk2U6k5N6t/U71WCpyzHyKVWhB5fJ+BXOkdZchgWJ0l0G+7KTUTuUBPb44tSOURE8D+lPSafMWBFEkTFYK2G59NVOOL1T/wDBxNv2UrW4bi3FcXFCS0wanca2cU5PrqV/aHR0pzxp1ZSZ9dYrW7gb3q6greq8VorRvlNJepu0z5m2Vfzt60K0ecGn5rsfQW7m2oXlGNWm+axKOdYy6iHHYAAAAbIcJJAEYC4FAMbuorOmqcKL/qTguNfTU1TPIfZpL/VxUm8qDwmz1yUhQUDJsOIbI0XSAyOrWjCLlOUYpdZNJGH3q37pwhOjbPiqNcLqflj3wEL+u5tu9p1bep7t8Xu6ii304uuDK8OUSbApyWy5TeX7ypxSb6vqMpS+E4/PPbr8Ln1oYYtDPToT3MNCChNZwc9XdanUUoro+viVLlaEU4voMqzeFhN9xz611ybq2k9cnOnTaep3Kk3yaZy7x66Itmo6jnyiRyRO4kVSJWVKqshg+oRlYnUkGWbai6koxXVlWJrN2Nna8cvp4BJ2lfjX7EoKlTjHwWTj+0J5o0/M7tJmU3/us+7p/U6LOZTl7WHNPuTvNOxrLPxUptKce3+SMwwRBt9QWdzGpCM4PMZJNfYnPLvZfvUsKyrN8Sb91N9V+k9RGQEYoMAYAAAeZ2exPwm14cC/p1IOcfDTVHoDKt7aKVWjV601j7orbZ21QtIOdWaXVQTXG/oKCujkzu8m9lCzi48SqVMaQi08PxPPd5d+K1xJxoSlSpYxppKXiZGpVlJtybk3zbeWa6XHW2zvJdXb/q1Hw9IR0jFdjkQWWl3eBuS1s2nx1qcVzlOKA3ssbJU9jwjFPSKk+5lbSeUem31r/oHTxypLReR5fYPmuzZz/kZdHhqerE5VVcM89MnXqIqXFHjicjoqWjJMWceFPGNe5So1XHR80WpTjLHxY0HIXeK1eeiwkn3OVcU1r9ToV4qPXJQq1ea6FMsarnzWCtVmievIozeSuInqo5sbgUvbNsJVZr9OdS0iVTbH2ZKrJPlFc/E3ljRUI8K0wV7C1jTioxR0YovnKWtJoSwef743HHXx+lYNzWqcMW+yPM9sV/eVZy8cD38LCiAAQUTW1eVOcZwbjODUotc00e0bib6/jM0q3DCrBLDzhTXdeJ4iSUasoSUoycZLVOLw0AfUaA8Z3W9o1Wi1Tus1afLi/NHz7nrGytrULqmqlGpGcX0yuJeaGS7gBf8A7oABzqnJeS9Dxj2h/wB0/oKAjY8AAADq7r/3lt/vUADn0Po+4/2Uv2f9p45Y/PU/fL1YAT/I+KeFcqCU+TADhdf8cm4+djY80AG4zUF1yObU/wCooGsp1TuCqwAvn4nTGardb5X9QAtn6lWopFhAB0z4jr6qbS+SXkzzK4+aXm/UAMb+NYRAAEFAAAABvfZX/cMAAPaAABk//9k=";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I just started learning p5js about a week ago, so sorry if my code is bad or sloppy...
Editor:https://editor.p5js.org/

Comment: I updated your question to have a reasonable title, and to include a runnable snippet version of your code. For future reference "Does anybody know trigonometry?" is decidedly not okay as a title for a StackOverflow question! You need to read and follow [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to be a good member of this community.

Comment: Also, I suggest you remove that image data from the example, since it is irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically the use of trigonometry in this example is actually unnecessary. The objective is to move a circle positioned at `aiX, aiY` closer to a second circle positioned at `payerX, playerY`. It is trivial to compute a vector from the `ai` position to the `player` position by taking the difference between the two components in each direction: `playerX - aiX` is the offset from `ai` to `player` in the horizontal direction, and `playerY - aiY` is the offset from `ai` to `player` in the vertical direction. Obviously you won't want to change the position of the `ai` circle by the entire offset, since that would be instant game over. If you want to fix the speed of movement at a particular level, you simply need to divide each component by the length of the vector, and then if you want a speed other than 1, multiply by the desired speed. Here is the code that does this without any trigonometry:

```js
let aiX = 200;
let aiY = 0;
let playerX = 200;
let playerY = 200;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  if (isKeyPressed && keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    playerY = playerY - 5;
  }
  if (isKeyPressed && keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    playerY = playerY + 5;
  }
  if (isKeyPressed && keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    playerX = playerX + 5;
  }
  if (isKeyPressed && keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    playerX = playerX - 5;
  }

  fill(0, 255, 0);
  ellipse(playerX, playerY, 50, 50);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(aiX, aiY, 50, 50);

  let offsetX = playerX - aiX;
  let offsetY = playerY - aiY;
  // pythagorean theorem: given a right triangle, the length of the
  // hypotenuse is the square root of side A squared plus side B squared
  let length = sqrt(offsetX * offsetX + offsetY * offsetY);
  offsetX = offsetX / length;
  offsetY = offsetY / length;
  
  // The total distance moved when incrementing will now be 1
  aiX += offsetX;
  aiY += offsetY;

  if (dist(playerX, playerY, aiX, aiY) < 50) {
    console.log("GAMEOVER");
    reset();
  }
}

function reset() {
  playerX = 200;
  playerY = 200;
  aiX = 200;
  aiY = 15;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

However, since you asked about the trigonometry, here's how the original example works:

The `atan2` function, which implements the inverse tangent function (a.k.a arctangent), takes the vertical offset between two points and the horizontal offset between the two points, and returns the angle of the line between the two points relative to some reference direction (the positive X direction). This is the inverse of the tangent function which takes an angle, and returns the ratio of the opposite to the adjacent sides of a right triangle with that angle. The reason for using `atan2` which takes the two offsets separately vs. the `atan` function which takes the ratio as a single value, is that `atan` will not return correct angles when the x offset is negative.

Now, once you have the angle of a line from the `ai` position to the `player` position, you can use other trigonometric functions to convert back to offsets: namely sine and cosine (i.e. `sin` and `cos`). The sine function takes an angle and returns the ratio of the opposite side of a right triangle with that angle and its hypotenuse. The cosine function takes an angle and returns the ratio of the adjacent side of a right triangle with that angle and its hypotenuse. So if you use `sin(angle)` as the vertical offset to move by, and `cos(angle)` as the horizontal offset, then you are moving in the direction of `angle` by an offset of `1`.

To better understand all of this I recommend you watch the [first few chapters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKEaK7WNLzM&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZV4yEcW3uDwOgGXKUUsPOM&index=10) of The Nature of Code by Daniel Shiffman.

I also think [this p5.js sketch by spencer eastcott](https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1198096) is helpful for visualizing these concepts.

Comment: Thank you I'll watch the videos!!!

Comment: So I watched the Video and i didn't really understand... Should I learn the basics more?

Comment: I would strongly recommend watching some more videos or reading more articles, a very helpful YouTuber I watched when I began with p5.js is "The coding train" He has a full tutorial available to watch. Here is his entire tutorial set: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6YrbSJBg32eTzUU50E2B8Ch